# Android storage showing the incorrect amount

Tags: android, local-storage

I did a test of available storage for my app, which uses local private storage. No matter what method I call it does not show what Android file browser or Windows browser shows.

Here is my code:

```
public static long getAvailableMemory()
    {
    Log.i(TAG, "getAvailableMemory: start");
    long bytesAvailable = 0;
    try
        {
        StatFs stat;
        // Root
        stat = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        bytesAvailable = stat.getAvailableBytes();
        Log.d(TAG, "Root.Absolute.AvailableBytes = " + bytesAvailable);
        bytesAvailable = stat.getFreeBytes();
        Log.d(TAG, "Root.Absolute.FreeBytes = " + bytesAvailable);
        // Data
        stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        bytesAvailable = stat.getAvailableBytes();
        Log.d(TAG, "Data.Absolute.AvailableBytes = " + bytesAvailable);
        bytesAvailable = stat.getFreeBytes();
        Log.d(TAG, "Data.Absolute.FreeBytes = " + bytesAvailable);
        // External
        stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        bytesAvailable = stat.getAvailableBytes();
        Log.d(TAG, "External.Absolute.AvailableBytes = " + bytesAvailable);
        bytesAvailable = stat.getFreeBytes();
        Log.d(TAG, "External.Absolute.FreeBytes = " + bytesAvailable);
        // Local
        File file = new File(Settings.pathToThumbnails);
        bytesAvailable = file.getUsableSpace();
        Log.d(TAG, "File.UsableSpace = " + bytesAvailable);
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    //      Log.d(TAG, "getAvailableMemory: bytesAvailable = " + bytesAvailable);
    return bytesAvailable;
    }
```

Android file browser : 1.65GB

Windows file browser : 1,745,756,160 (1.62)

Running the app, Log :

```
12-24 08:06:58.966 11835-11835 D/*~MAIN ACTIVITY: Root.Absolute.AvailableBytes = 209154048
12-24 08:06:58.966 11835-11835 D/*~MAIN ACTIVITY: Root.Absolute.FreeBytes = 209154048
12-24 08:06:58.966 11835-11835 D/*~MAIN ACTIVITY: Data.Absolute.AvailableBytes = 1769209856
12-24 08:06:58.966 11835-11835 D/*~MAIN ACTIVITY: Data.Absolute.FreeBytes = 1774452736
12-24 08:06:58.966 11835-11835 D/*~MAIN ACTIVITY: External.Absolute.AvailableBytes = 1748234240
12-24 08:06:58.966 11835-11835 D/*~MAIN ACTIVITY: External.Absolute.FreeBytes = 1748234240
12-24 08:06:58.966 11835-11835 D/*~MAIN ACTIVITY: File.UsableSpace = 1769205760
```

I am unsure of what actual figure to use for testing my app. I don't know where the 1.65 GB that Android reports comes from. I just want to know how much available storage is left for my app to save thumbnail images to local private storage.

Comment: What exactly do you believe is wrong here?  Those numbers are very close, especially when you consider the imperfect matchup of powers of 2 and powers of 10

Comment: I do not think 1.65 GB (Android reports) is close to 1.75 GB (External.AvailableBytes). But more importantly, which is the correct amount to do the error testing on. If I error check the Environment call but the actual amount is less, then it will be an error in writing the file.

Comment: External.AvailableBytes *is not* reporting "1.75 GB" it is reporting 1748234240 bytes.  If you take some time to understand what I just said about powers of 2 vs powers of 10, this is not a very big difference at all, and could be entirely explained by conditions changing over tests even a few milliseconds apart.  **If you are trying to write a file that large, especially to a device with barely that much space free, you are probably doing something very very wrong**

Comment: So is it safe to assume that I can use the External.AvailableBytes method with all confidence to error check if I can write a file to local storage?

Comment: No.  Unless the file you want to write is *well short* of the available space, you have to allow for another app writing something at the same time you are.  Writing gigabyte+ files to an Android device is not normal behavior at all.

Comment: I would assume then to simply use a try/catch and handle the catch then? (I am not writing a file that big, really small actually, but I want to be through in my error checking)

Comment: Yes.  You should use try / catch. Checking to see if there is enough space before writing (or whether the directory is writable, etc) may fail due to race conditions.

Comment: Thank you, one more question. Would you even go so far as to try/catch puts to shared preferences?